# How do I get Excel to look up customer names from another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two sheets in Excel i.e. sheet1 and sheet2.

In sheet1's column A there are account numbers of the customer and in column B there are names of the customers.

Now I want that in column A of sheet2 when I type any account number of the customer from sheet1's column A, it should show the name of the customer in column B which is written in sheet1's column b.

For example I am attaching a snapshot of both the sheets i.e. sheet1 and sheet2.

In the following image only the account no the customers in column A (in sheet2) will be typed by me and the name of the customers should automatically be appeared in column B in the front of the customer's account.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways I would do this: `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

In **sheet 2**, cell `B2`, use formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$11,2,false)
```

Drag this formula down as far as you require, where:

- `A2` is the first account code in **sheet 2** you wish to look up
- `$A$2` is the start location in **sheet 1** with the row column indicators preceded by a dollar sign (*the dollar signs mean this location is fixed, so will not change when copying*)
- `Sheet1!` is the instruction to tell Excel you are looking at a different sheet
- `$B$11` is the last item in the list and the column in which the data to be looked up occurs.
- `2` is the column count of the data you want to return (in this case `A` is **column 1** and `B` is **column 2**)
- `false` is the indicator to say that you want an **exact** match from your account number.  If the number doesn't exist, the error `#N/A` appears, otherwise you get the account name.

Alternatively, use a combination of the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions:
Again in `B2` type

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

Drag down as many cells as you need

This finds the row number in **sheet 1** which corresponds to the contents of `A2` in **sheet 2**, then returns the name located in column `B` in the same row.

The advantage of `INDEX`/`MATCH` is that if the data you want to look up is to the left of the data you are searching for, this will still work, whereas `VLOOKUP` can only look from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not a simple `vlookup`? In Sheet2 `=vlookup([cell reference to account number], [lookup in this array in this range in sheet1], [return this column in range], [true/false for match type])`.

[VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)

Answer (score -1):

lookup function can be used here.
there are two types of lookup functions
vlookup and hlookup.

with the help of LOOKUP function this problem can be solved.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.